# Why do I see router and not my real IIS?

Tags: router, port, port-forwarding, iis

I am trying to access IIS through web but unable to do so. Basically I have a router (which functions as router and modem) that is given by ISP and I have another router connected to the router given by ISP. My ISP's router can be visited through `192.168.0.1` and the router that I connected to ISP's router can be visited through `192.168.1.1`

Please see my ISP's router:

[image]

As you can see I have DMZ enabled for my router of `192.168.1.1`

Now please see my router of 192.168.1.1:

[image]

As you can see I added a virtual server for port 80 where 192.168.1.125 is my private IP.

I rebooted both of my modems an tried to visit my IP from: http://www.whatsmyip.org/

and after doing so, when I type my live IP I still see my router of 192.168.0.1 instead of my IIS. What am I missing?

**Note:** I have disabled Firewall on both of the routers.

Any help would be appreciated.